# Integrity constraint violation em "Many to Many" create - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Contexto: Ao cadastrar uma empresa, por de ser "anexado" vários clientes a ela e esse mesmo cliente pode ser "anexado" em outras empresas.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de banco de dados:

Model "Client":

```
public function enterprises()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Enterprise', 'enterprise_client');
}
```

Model "Enterprise":

```
public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Client', 'enterprise_client');
}
```

Pivot "enterprise_client":

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('enterprise_client', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('enterprise_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('enterprise_id')->references('id')->on('enterprises')->onDelete('restrict');
        $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('restrict');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Para salvar os dados:

```
if (isset($dataRequest['clients'])) {
            $enterprise->clients()->sync($dataRequest['clients']);
        }
```

"$dataRequest['clients']" é um array de ID's. "isset()" é para verificar se tem esse array no Request, pois durante o cadastro, o preenchimento de clientes não é obrigatório.

Porém, ao tentar salvar os dados, é me retornado o erro:

```
local.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my_project`.`enterprise_client`, CONSTRAINT `enterprise_client_client_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `clients` (`id`)) in /home/Workspace/MyProject/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:142
```

Utilizando `attach()` ao invés de `sync()` retorna o mesmo erro.

O que pode estar causando isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que percebi do seu problema, estão em causa apenas dois modelos (Entreprice e Client), nestes casos usa-se o método hasMany, no sentido em que uma empresa pode ter vários clientes, assim como um cliente pode estar em várias empresas. É uma relação directa entre duas tabelas.

O método `belongsToMany()` é usado para relações com mais tabelas, quando tens por exemplo, uma terceira tabela Pivot que faz as relações entre os clientes e as empresas.

Além disso, acho que as declarações não tem os parâmetros correctos. Deves colocar os ids que fazem as ligações entre os modelos:

```
public function enterprises()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Enterprise', 'enterprise_id');
}

public function clients()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Client', 'client_id');
}
```

EDIT:
Realmente não reparei na tabela pivot nos comentários, minha culpa.
Simulei todos os modelos e consegui inserir os registos na tabela pivot sem problemas. Usei este código para testar:

```
$enterprise = Enterprise::first();

$dataRequest['clients'][0] = '1';
$dataRequest['clients'][1] = '2';
$dataRequest['clients'][2] = '3';

if (isset($dataRequest['clients'])) {
 $enterprise->clients()->sync($dataRequest['clients']);
}
```

Tive o mesmo erro que você quando tentei inserir o id de um cliente que não existe. Por exemplo `$dataRequest['clients'][2] = '10';`

Podes adicionar um try / Catch para contornar este problema, os ids que existem são na mesma inseridos.

```
 $enterprise = Enterprise::first();

  $dataRequest['clients'][0] = '1';
  $dataRequest['clients'][1] = '2';
  $dataRequest['clients'][2] = '10';

  if (isset($dataRequest['clients'])) {

        try {
          $enterprise->clients()->sync($dataRequest['clients']);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
      }
  }
```

Comment: Eu já tenho essa 3 tabela pivot no meu modelo, eu disse isso na minha pergunta.

Comment: @MatheusdeMelo.F actualizei a minha resposta com código testado e que funciona. Espero que ajude.